# load a specific css and js files for a specific view page in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on  Cakephp 2.x

Currently, I am managing my views is like this: I have a `default.ctp` file in my `View/layout folder` where all the reusable data is (for example menu, side bar, footer) and all the css and js files are also imported there. Then I have a view pages in my `View/ControllerName/index.ctp` file in which I am displaying the records.

Now what I want is to load specific css and js files for particular view page. How can I manage this?? Because at that time my all view pages is getting all the css and js files from the default.ctp file. But I want to load default.ctp layout as well but I want that if let's suppose I am calling a different view page then it select some css and js files from the default.ctp and skip the rest of files

Hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a posible approach:
In your `beforeFilter` function in `AppController`:

```
$this->set('loadXCss', false);
$this->set('loadYCss', false);
$this->set('loadZCss', false);
```

Then in any Controller, you should decide to show or not the css:

```
$this->set('loadZCss', true);
```

And last, in the layout:

```
<?php
echo this->Html->css('main.css', null, array('media' => 'screen,projection'));
if ( $loadXCss ) echo this->Html->css('x.css', null, array('media' => 'screen,projection'));
if ( $loadYCss ) echo this->Html->css('y.css', null, array('media' => 'screen,projection'));
if ( $loadZCss ) echo this->Html->css('z.css', null, array('media' => 'screen,projection'));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AppController::beforeRender() function; add the following line:

```
$this->set('controller_name', $this->name);
```

In your default.ctp file, you can do an `if` or `switch` statement based on the $controller_name viewVar, and display some CSS/JS based on the value of it.

Or you can simply add overrides to other CSS and JS files and call those individually on each particular view you want to show.